# Simplifying the modification of strings from a dynamic list?

Tags: python, string, replace, split

I want to change a list of strings from one format to another.

An example of a full list can be found here: https://gist.github.com/ProGamerGov/1d728e7ca4cc52abf398277642e4ee78

Some examples of what I am trying to do:

```
Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
```

To:

```
(2): Conv2d(3 -> 64, 3x3, 1,1, 1,1)
```

And this:

```
Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
```

To this:

```
(8): Conv2d(64 -> 128, 3x3, 1,1, 1,1)
```

My current code setup looks like this:

```
def modify_text(text, new): 
    return text.replace(", ","*", 1).replace(", ", new, 1)

for i, layer in enumerate(net): 
        if "Conv2d" in str(layer):
           layer = str(layer).replace(","," ->", 1)
           layer = modify_text(layer, "x").replace("kernel_size=(", "").replace("stride=(", "").replace("padding=(", "").replace(")","", 3)
           layer = modify_text(modify_text(layer, ","), ",").replace("*",", ")
           print("  (" + str(i+1) + "): " + layer)
```

But I feel like I there could be a better looking/simpler way to do this?

Edit, I've simplified my setup down to this:

```
regx_map = r'(2d).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*'
regx_pool = r'(2d).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*'
for i, layer in enumerate(net): 
     if "Conv2d" in str(layer):
          print("  (" + str(i+1) + "): " + re.sub(regx_map, r'\1(\2 -> \3, \4x\5, \6,\7, \8,\9)', str(layer)))
     elif "MaxPool2d" in str(layer) or "AvgPool2d" in str(layer):
          print("  (" + str(i+1) + "): " + re.sub(regx_pool, r'\1(\2x\2, \3,\3)', str(layer)))
     else:
          print("  (" + str(i+1) + "): " + "nn." + str(layer).split("(", 1)[0])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could  use a regular expression to match:

```
import re
s = 'Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))'
regx = r'(Conv2d).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*'

print(re.sub(regx, r'\1(\2 -> \3, \4x\5, \6,\7,\8,\9)', s))
```

Output:

```
Conv2d(3 -> 64, 3x3, 1,1,1,1)
```

If you wanted to make the regex slightly more robust at the cost of it being quite long:

```
(Conv2d)\((\d+),\s(\d+),\skernel_size=\((\d+),\s(\d+)\),\sstride=\((\d+),\s(\d+)\),\spadding=\((\d+),\s(\d+)\)\)
```

Try it out [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/yD0Itm/1)

Comment: Thanks for the help! How would I for example, change 
`Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))` into
`64 3 3 3` with regex?

Comment: I'm trying to put `MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)` into the same setup as your regx variable above, but I can't get it to work. But I guess the format is slightly different?

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

Comment: I need it to look like: `MaxPool2d(2x2, 2,2)`. Also, depending on the user choice, the "MaxPool" string will be like this instead: `AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0)`. The "AvgPool" string through needs to end up in the same format as it does for MaxPool: `AvgPool2d(2x2, 2,2)`. I'm not sure if these two strings are similar enough to just merge them together into one regx thing, or not.

Comment: Maybe the best option might be to define a single regx variable that creates a map for all 3 string setups/formats, and then I could just add the `MaxPool2d`, `AvgPool2d`, or `Conv2d` when I want to print a layer name/string.

Comment: For the single map idea, I could just take the numbers that occur past "2d". But I am not sure how to do that?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for anything but Conv2d: `regx_map = r'(2d).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to parse the signatures of the functions in the strings, convert the parameters to the desired syntax, and then and then use `re.sub` to add the new signatures:

```
import re
import itertools
def signature(header):
  s = re.findall('(?<=\()[\w\W]+(?=\)$)', header)
  return re.split(',\s(?=\w\w)', s[0]) if s else ''

def combine_args(d):
   if '=' in d:
      return '{}x{}'.format(*re.findall('\d+', d)) if 'kernel_size' in d and len(re.findall('\d+', d)) == 2 else '{},{}'.format(*re.findall('\d+', d)) if len(re.findall('\d+', d)) == 2 else d
   return d

def combine_header(d):
  vals = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(d, key=lambda x:x.isdigit())]
  return list(itertools.chain(*[[' -> '.join(b)] if a else [combine_args(i) for i in b] for a, b in vals]))

lines = ['TVLoss()', 'Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'StyleLoss((gram): GramMatrix()(crit): MSELoss())', 'Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)', 'Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'StyleLoss((gram): GramMatrix()(crit): MSELoss())', 'Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)', 'Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'StyleLoss((gram): GramMatrix()(crit): MSELoss())', 'Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)', 'Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'StyleLoss((gram): GramMatrix()(crit): MSELoss())', 'Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'ContentLoss((crit): MSELoss())', 'Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)', 'Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'StyleLoss((gram): GramMatrix()(crit): MSELoss())']
final_lines = [re.sub('(?<=\()[\w\W]+(?=\)$)', ', '.join(combine_header(c)), a) for a, c in zip(lines, map(signature, lines))]
```

Output:

```
['TVLoss()', 'Conv2d(3 -> 64, 3x3, 1,1, 1,1)', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'StyleLoss((gram): GramMatrix()(crit): MSELoss())', 'Conv2d(64 -> 64, 3x3, 1,1, 1,1)', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)', 'Conv2d(64 -> 128, 3x3, 1,1, 1,1)', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'StyleLoss((gram): GramMatrix()(crit): MSELoss())', 'Conv2d(128 -> 128, 3x3, 1,1, 1,1)', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)', 'Conv2d(128 -> 256, 3x3, 1,1, 1,1)', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'StyleLoss((gram): GramMatrix()(crit): MSELoss())', 'Conv2d(256 -> 256, 3x3, 1,1, 1,1)', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'Conv2d(256 -> 256, 3x3, 1,1, 1,1)', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'Conv2d(256 -> 256, 3x3, 1,1, 1,1)', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)', 'Conv2d(256 -> 512, 3x3, 1,1, 1,1)', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'StyleLoss((gram): GramMatrix()(crit): MSELoss())', 'Conv2d(512 -> 512, 3x3, 1,1, 1,1)', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'ContentLoss((crit): MSELoss())', 'Conv2d(512 -> 512, 3x3, 1,1, 1,1)', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'Conv2d(512 -> 512, 3x3, 1,1, 1,1)', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)', 'Conv2d(512 -> 512, 3x3, 1,1, 1,1)', 'ReLU(inplace)', 'StyleLoss((gram): GramMatrix()(crit): MSELoss())']
```